# close client before finishing command postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Let's say that I would like to create an index. It will take some time. I use pgadmin. Let's say that when query is being executed pgadmin crashed for some reason (for example computer is restarted).

What would be the status of that index. Would it keep on being created and finally at some point it would be created with success or it will fail immedately or it will fail aftger some time?

Is there any way to check what is the status of index being created?  (Im using postgres version 10.x)

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to answer the question if we do not know the reason for the crash of an application. If it was not caused by a server failure it is likely that the index was created correctly. You can check this by querying the system catalog `pg_index`. You have to know the index name, e.g.:

```
select indexrelid::regclass, indisvalid
from pg_index
where indexrelid::regclass::text = 'my_table_unique_col_key'
```

Per [the documantaion:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-index.html)

> indisvalid - If true, the index is currently valid for queries. False means the index is possibly incomplete: it must still be modified by INSERT/UPDATE operations, but it cannot safely be used for queries. If it is unique, the uniqueness property is not guaranteed true either.

If the index is not created yet (or at all due to a query failure) the above query returns no rows. You can check whether the query that creates the index is still running (see [Dynamic Statistics Views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-DYNAMIC-VIEWS-TABLE)):

```
select *
from pg_stat_activity
where query ilike 'create index%'
```

Comment: Ok but how to check (for example in create index concurrently) if it is in invalid state because it is still being built or because something failed?

Comment: Thanks but for create index concurrently I think that index will be there instantly but with status invalid :)

Comment: Yes, indeed. Therefore you should first check whether the query is still running.